# Exec command for kde plasma to enable remote host controller(virtual desktop session)

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde

I want to access my KDE Plasma desktop remotely on my Android and so I've installed Chrome remote desktop app in Chrome (latest versions). I followed the official [tutorial](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) but there's need to enable computer at remote desktop host controller so to do they explained to create virtual desktop session.

> #### Create a virtual desktop session
>
> 1. Look in `/usr/share/xsessions/` for the `.desktop` file for your preferred desktop environment. For example, Cinnamon has a file named
>    `"cinnamon.desktop"` with the following command:
>
>    ```
>     gnome-session --session=cinnamon`
>    ```
> 2. Create a file called `.chrome-remote-desktop-session` in your home  directory with the following content:
>
>    ```
>     exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "<YOUR_EXEC_COMMAND>"
>    ```
> 3. Replace `<YOUR_EXEC_COMMAND>` with the command at the end of your `.desktop` file. In the example for Cinnamon, the correct command is
>
>    ```
>     exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session 'gnome-session --session=cinnamon'
>    ```
>
>    Desktops require some additional code. The full command is
>
>    ```
>     DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session 'gnome-session --session=ubuntu'
>    ```
> 4. Save the file called `.chrome-remote-desktop-session`​.

So I did unsuccessful try with

```
exec /usr/bin/startkde  '/usr/bin/startkde'
```

and

```
exec /usr/share/sddm  '/usr/bin/startkde'
```

I used `sddm` cause there's no `lightdm` in KDE Plasma.
I've followed steps but don't know the Exec command for KDE Plasma for plasma session. So what proper Exec command is there to successfully create virtual desktop session?

Comment: Did you try `exec /usr/share/sddm /usr/bin/plasma-desktop`?

Comment: @dessert Tried now but not working. Is it proper and full command to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is sort of old but I found the solution. The exec command that should go into .chrome-remote-desktop-session is;
exec /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession "/usr/bin/startkde"
That command works for me on kubuntu.

Comment: Tried that but it did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer came from : https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0A7i2OnRjy4Q/?hl=sv

and so in my file i got :

```
export $(dbus-launch)
exec /usr/bin/startkde
```

it works but unfortunately it start a new session it doesn't take the control of the current session