# Desktop fails to start, stuck in a login loop - Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, plasma-5

As the title suggests, I'm stuck in a login loop. I've tried the other suggestions askubuntu gave me, to no avail. My system and all software is up to date (as of Tuesday Jan 22). Can't tell if this should be places in the KDE, X, or PLASMA forums, as I'm having a hard time understanding the issue.

I had earlier been using these two resources (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en and [Exec command for kde plasma to enable remote host controller(virtual desktop session)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962756/exec-command-for-kde-plasma-to-enable-remote-host-controllervirtual-desktop-ses)) to get Google Remote Desktop working with Kubuntu. I was successful, and it didn't seem to break my install. It had me create a ~/.chrome-remote-desktop file which tells the remote desktop service to create another desktop session to use. Maybe the existence of two sessions broke something? Prior to rebooting and hitting the login loop, I was customizing my desktop background/icons, etc. It's entirely possible I messed something up when troubleshooting the remote desktop connection, or something else.

When I get to the GUI login manager, I enter my password, hit enter, and the screen goes black for about 3-8 seconds, then the initialization pops back up (black background, wall of text starting things up again), then brings me back to the login page. If I enter the password again, it goes back to the initialization, then back to the login, so on and so forth.

If I hit ctrl+alt+F3, I'm able to drop to the console/terminal and login. Here is the output of my ~/.xsession-errors:

```
Xsession: X session started for mjanik at Tue Jan 22 13:25:03 EST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/mjanik/.Xauthority
localuser:mjanik being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/plasma.mandatory.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=mjanik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/plasma.default.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/mjanik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/mjanik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/plasma:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=mjanik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PAM_KWALLET_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet.socket
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/mjanik/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg:/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kf5-settings
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
kcm_input: Using X11 backend
startkde: Starting up...
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher'
kdeinit5: Launched KLauncher, pid = 1803, result = 0
Waiting for already running klauncher to exit.
Waiting for already running klauncher to exit.
Another instance of klauncher is already running!
kdeinit5: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0) failed: : Connection refused

Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Configuring Lock Action
ksmserver: "/run/user/1000/KSMserver"
ksmserver: KSMServer: SetAProc_loc: conn  0 , prot= local , file= @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1807
ksmserver: KSMServer: SetAProc_loc: conn  1 , prot= unix , file= /tmp/.ICE-unix/1807
ksmserver: KSMServer::restoreSession  "saved at previous logout"
startkde: Shutting down...
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0) failed: : Connection refused
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
startkde: Done.
Qt: Couldn't interpret the _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I have tried removing .Xauthority, to no avail. I've also tried several troubleshooting methods relating to the .xsession-errors output using google, etc., but I I can't seem to find anything that has actually worked. Some red flags that stood out to me, but I haven't been able to find resolutions for:

```
Waiting for already running klauncher to exit.
Another instance of klauncher is already running!
kdeinit5: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
```

and

```
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0) failed: : Connection refused
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
```

and

```
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Hopefully somebody here will be able to shed some light on the situation. I'll provide more info on the system if need be! I LOVE Kubuntu! After updating everything was running so smoothly on my system for a day or two, then I think I messed it up, haha.

Thanks again for all the help!
All the best.

EDIT:

I solved this. It was google chrome remote desktop causing a discrepancy with the x-server. I guess it can't multiple sessions running at once, which is what the remote desktop package did when it booted up. I removed it all, and was able to login no problem.

Comment: You might want to post your solution as an answer to this question. It may seem odd to "answer" your own question, but it may help other users that have the same problem and is acceptable on AskUbuntu to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Google Chrome Remote Desktop package doesn't exactly play nice with Kubuntu 18.04. After a reboot I guess the remoting daemon created a second instance of Klauncher and X-server, which caused a discrepancy in the execution of the Plasma 5 desktop when I went to login on my main (physical) display. I kind of realized that google's remoting agent was setting up another virtual desktop for the connecting client to use, so I used

```
apt-cache search chrome
```

to find the chrome-remote-desktop-beta deb package I had installed from the google link I provided in my first post, and removed it. I also removed Google Chrome for good measure, though I'm sure this wasn't necessary. I use Firefox, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a console guru, you can break the login loop by providing incorrect password once (letting the login to fail) and then repeating login with correct password. After that the KDE starts normally. Remove *Remote Desktop* extension in Google Chrome at first. Then open *Muon Package Manager*, search for *chrome-remote-desktop* package and remove it too :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with KDE Neon 18.04.

My current solution is a workaround:

- Boot up the computer, get greeted by `sddm` login (you might have other display manager like `lightdm`, then adjust one of the commands below)
- Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to go to command line
- Execute `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --stop`
- Execute `sudo service sddm restart` (Maybe optional, did not check)
- Log in successfully
- Remember to execute `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start` before you leave and need to connect to the desktop remotely